# A friendly reminder to not use the question's comment section as a place for discussion

Tags: discussion

Recently we have seen a large number of increased comments in regards to critique questions that include questions, ideas, comments, and a general debate but I would like to please ask not use the comments for such and I would like to encourage users to possibly see if you can migrate the responses to chat.  That said I have created a chat just for this instance called [Graphic Design Critique Discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15161/graphic-design-critique-discussions).

If you have any questions for the OP I would encourage you to ask them to go the chat with an invitation and if they cannot due to rep I know a mod would be more than happy do invite them in to discuss their question.

If you need a snippet for a comment invite to chat:

`Do you mind if we can discuss your critique in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15161/graphic-design-critique-discussions)?`

Comment: Can we discuss this in comments here, please? :)

Comment: what a rebel...

Comment: I think that was a typo.. you meant a p rather than a b right?

Comment: So who's been following the World Cup? My bet's on Germany, they've really nailed their fast attacking movements

Comment: Definitely not England! T_T Discouraging comments isn't really a good move, they are often more necessary than unnecessary. Flagging the last comment in a chain that has been rendered obsolete by updates, would notify a mod so that they could clean it up. Unfortunately when I did so my flag was *declined*.

Comment: Im not discouraging comments at all.  Sometimes they are needed but it would appear when someone asks a critique question some members appear to have a full conversation in the comments and that is what I am trying to prevent.  Im trying to encourage providing an answer and for members to edit their answers with their comments.

Comment: Hey, nice, I totally predicted the 2014 world cup, at the end of the group stage! Darn, why did I just say "my bet's on..." instead of actually putting a bet on it...

Answer (score 6):

Good idea with the specialist chat rooms, but it's worth drawing a distinction between helpful comments (such as asking for and getting clarification, and relevant observations) and less helpful comments like sarcasm, comments not about the design e.g. company name, etc. There will always be a fine line between the two.

I think a good approach would be burning clarification comments as soon as they are edited into the question, burning the non-helpful comments whenever there become too many, but maybe leaving or summarising the "potentially helpful observation" comments unless an answer explains the same point better: it can be useful and interesting to see the range of things people pick up on.

Comment: I think all observations on a critique question should be left as answers not as comments. Easier to vote on, comment on those critiques, and edit if the person updates their design/question which often happens.

Comment: Completely agree with both the answer and the comment.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with this is that a lot of comments are not answers but clarifications, and are helpful to anyone reading the topic, not just the creator.

Comment: I think you're missing what the message is.  In no way am I discouraging comments.  All I am requesting is on critique questions before you post a comment, if your comment would serve better in the chat please take the discussion to chat.  If its a valued comment then it should be an answer.  If you have provided an answer with a valued comment then you should edit your answer to include the comment.  If all you're posting is an opinion then it should be taken to chat.  If you have a question leave it in the comment section and once its edited then delete your comment and add it to the answer

Comment: The problem is for example there was a critique with about 20+ comments on it, the question was then edited, and more comments were left. That makes it hard for everyone to follow which comments were pre-edit and which were after. Because most of the comments were really "micro-answers." That users felt were too small to warrant an answer but worth commenting on and then discussing at length.

Answer (score 1):

**Users who like to use the comments section as a forum or a personal Facebook feed should simply post their own answers.** By doing so, they will also have more room to express their "opinion" or what they think is a better answer. Asking for a clarification is alright when it's done in good faith.

I noticed some users do not post any answer but post endless comments that sometimes end up being off-topic or are clearly going on a tangent that only them are seeing. There's unfortunately no way for the other users to "down vote" these comments, and flagging them is not always efficient. Sometimes there's nothing more to say than "it's a free world, people do what works for them," especially in design; there's often many ways to achieve one result.

But when they post misleading information (or worse, useless opinions) this often requires some clarification. I guess if something was wrong in the answers, they would simply post their own correct answer...? There's already a down vote feature for answers that don't make sense. They wouldn't survive too long with their opinions or tangents in some of the other SE where sources and references are required.

I find it unfortunate if moderators need to start policing every comments and editing them. Users should simply learn to comment and keep in mind the mission of SE (and leave their ego at home)... and maybe **read twice some answers *before commenting too fast*** (eg. test the techniques, research and verify the details of the answers, understand the "nuances" of the english language, etc.)

Comment: Actually you're incorrect in regards to flagging them and what we do with them.  SE mods do go back after a post is no longer hot or is of a certain age and when the comments no longer serve a purpose we remove them to clean up the Q&A format.

Comment: You probably clean them after it happened, maybe weeks or months after but still, the comments that shouldn't be there kept being made because the rules are not reinforced.  Some are even slightly trollish and insulting the people who ask questions; it's a bit intimidating when the questions or answers by new users make sense. I do think it's inefficient and in a few years if GD:SE gets bigger, you'll need to stop the fail trail of comments as they are made to not lose control on this. You'll probably be required to do so anyway because it will simply get worse.